# GRUB 2 dual boot freeze for a few seconds

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Sorry for asking this question again, asked it here a long time ago but didn't get any answers.

Since I setted up dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows 8 I have this "problem", grub menu shows up, if I press any key, everything freezes for about 2-5 seconds, after that everything works fine.

It's kind of annoying if I just want to select to boot windows and have to wait for "so long"

I couldn't find any answers, maybe someone knows how to fix this

Comment: I've never heard of that problem. You might try another EFI boot manager, at least to see if the problem persists with a different boot manager. Most EFIs provide a built-in boot manager you can access by pressing a function key at boot (which one varies between computers). There are also several other EFI boot loaders and managers for Linux, as noted on [this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) Most will require you to disable Secure Boot, but that might be worth it for a test.

Comment: Same problem here with Linux Mint 17.3 and 18, except there's no need to press a key to freeze everything.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this to be a Grub bug. I reported it at https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1603261.